# "Ambiguous column name" error on one particular server

Tags: sql, sql-server

This simple query throws the "Ambiguous column name TaskID" error **on one db-server only**. This is ridiculous. We tested this with the same database structure on different servers and different versions of SQL Server (2005 / 2008), and it's only THIS particular client's server that throws the error. I'm actually frustrated.

```
SELECT Tasks.TaskID
FROM Tasks
INNER JOIN TaskHelpers ON TaskHelpers.TaskID = Tasks.TaskID
ORDER BY TaskID
```

Yes, I know I can put `Tasks.TaskID` into the `order by` clause, but for some reasons I can't.

Comment: I have NEVER figured out why you have to manually specify which one of a joined column you're referring to. Surely if they're joined they're going to be the same anyway!? (might be some weird index stuff I don't get I guess)

Comment: Sounds interesting (+1). Now, what is the question??

Comment: if the problem doesn't persist on other servers, then maybe you should check for sql updates, or some setting maybe?

Comment: look at the compatibility mode you are running in on each of these DBs, there are documented differences in when the table name/alias is required or not in the ORDER BY clause.  See my answer below for links and more info.

Comment: @Ed Woodcock: they might not be the same, example when you use LEFT JOIN.  now for why the database doesn't figure out when the ON clause has exactly same name, i guess the database has generalize parser for all types of joins, be it LEFT JOIN, INNER JOIN, etc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wow. The problem was with the database compatibility mode. It was set to "80" (sql 2000). I've set it to 90 and the query works fine now.

More info on compatibility levels can be found here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms178653(SQL.90).aspx

Comment: You changed the compatibility level? Without findoing out why it was set that way? Very bad idea. You may be breaking a lot of things. Never change a compitibilty level unless you positively know it can be changed. If someone did this on our server they'd get fired.

Comment: @HLGEM welcome to the world of consulting. We didn't change it, the client did :(

Answer (score 12):

You will get the ambiguous column name error if you run your query on sql server 2000, or under compatibility level 80 or less. On sql server 2005/2008 with compatibility level 90 or better, yur query runs fine.

From the order by clause docs:

"In SQL Server 2005, qualified column names and aliases are resolved to columns listed in the FROM clause. If order_by_expression is not qualified, the value must be unique among all columns listed in the SELECT statement."

Comment: yes, you're right! Ray, we posted the same answer within a minute ;)

Answer (score 8):

My Momma said **always qualify EVERY column in a query with a table name/alias**  just like "always include all column names in INSERTs" and justs like "don't SELECT *", etc.

Other than making it easier because it is self documenting the source code, you prevent this error if you ever add/change columns.

**check your compatibility levels, there are differences between them and the how ORDER BY works!**

In general, in compatibility level 90 and higher, the default level for SQL Server 2008, an ORDER BY without a table name/alias statement produces the error.

[ALTER DATABASE Compatibility Level (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510680.aspx) see section: Differences Between Compatibility Level 80 and Level 90

**Compatibility-level setting of 80**

> WHEN binding the column references in
>   the ORDER BY list to the columns
>   defined in the SELECT list, column
>   ambiguities are ignored and column
>   prefixes are sometimes ignored. This
>   can cause the result set to return in
>   an unexpected order.
>
> For example, an ORDER BY clause with a
>   single two-part column
>   (.) that is used
>   as a reference to a column in a SELECT
>   list is accepted, but the table alias
>   is ignored. Consider the following
>   query.
>
> SELECT c1 = -c1 FROM t_table AS x
>   ORDER BY x.c1
>
> When executed, the column prefix is
>   ignored in the ORDER BY. The sort
>   operation does not occur on the
>   specified source column (x.c1) as
>   expected; instead it occurs on the
>   derived c1 column that is defined in
>   the query. The execution plan for this
>   query shows that the values for the
>   derived column are computed first and
>   then the computed values are sorted.

**Compatibility-level setting of 90**

> Errors are raised on column ambiguities.
>   Column prefixes, if any, specified in 
>   ORDER BY are not ignored when binding 
>   to a column defined in the SELECT list.
>
> Consider the following query.
>
> SELECT c1 = -c1 FROM t_table AS x ORDER BY x.c1
>
> When executed, the column prefix in the 
>   ORDER BY clause is not ignored. The sort
>   operation occurs on the specified source
>   column (x.c1) as expected. The execution
>   plan for this query shows that the sort
>   operator orders the rows returned from t_table
>   and then the values for the derived column
>   c1 defined in the SELECT list are computed.

Comment: I'm confused. The text from Microsoft website says that when level is 80, the ambiguity is ignored, when level is 90 then ambiguity errors are raised. But it turned to be exactly the opposite (check the other answers). Am I right?

Answer (score 5):

You can specify the index of the column to sort instead:

```
SELECT Tasks.TaskID
FROM Tasks
INNER JOIN TaskHelpers ON TaskHelpers.TaskID = Tasks.TaskID
order by 1
```

Comment: Why the downvote? If you don't explain what it is that you think is wrong, it can't improve the answer.

Comment: Because the answer is wrong. There should not be an error when there is one column with that name/alias in the `SELECT` clause and that name is referenced in the `ORDER BY`. See **[SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c16f95/1)** The error was due to a bug in some old versions/compatibility levels of SQL-Server, that has been fixed

Comment: @ypercube: It appears that SQL Server actually does that, at least in newer versions. Do you have any reference to *why* it does that? Why are the fields that are selected used as default for the order by?

Comment: That's what all DBMS do (at least those that I know). You can try the SQL-Fiddle. Oracle, MySQL and Postgres behave the same way.

Comment: The SQL standard probably has a thorough explanation but I find that quite hard to read. You can find a [draft here](http://www.wiscorp.com/sql20nn.zip). I think the explanation is in page 208 (in the lines: *"a) if N=1 ..."*) but I wouldn't bet my life on it :)

Answer (score 1):

what if you try with identifiers? By using these identifiers SQL server know which column to order by. I never done it in any other way and never had any problems. I don't exactly why sql needs these identifiers, it's obvious he doesn't know where to order by when there are ambigious columnnames. Try something like;

```
SELECT t.TaskID
FROM Tasks t
INNER JOIN TaskHelpers th ON th.TaskID = t.TaskID
order by t.TaskID
```

EDIT:
And what's the reason you can't? SQL throwing an error?

Comment: No. Actually, my predecessor constructed the SQL-query code in multiple business-logic operations, and the query in the question is a VERY simplified version of the query... that actually features sub-queries, unions etc

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean you can't? It's clear that both Tasks and TaskHelpers has a column named TaskID. You need to indicate which table the column in the Order By is associated with.