# SQL Server doesn't detect ambiguity

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have following SQL which should throw an error:

> Ambiguous column name

since `conferencetitle` column is in 2 tables; `course` and `coursesession`.

Please note im selecting this column only once.

```
SELECT 
    CourseSessionID, CourseSessionNum, 
    usrCourseSessionNum, 
    CourseSession.ConferenceTitle, 
    ConferenceDescription, MaxParticipants, 
    NumParticipants, 
    openSeats = ISNULL(MaxParticipants, 0) - ISNULL(NumParticipants, 0), 
    WaitingList, WaitingListCap, 
    SessionCancelled, 
    StartDate, SchedTime, SchedDate, StartTime, 
    ShowThruDate, CourseSession.RegStartDate, 
    ExtraCostCreditInfo, Days, IsMaster, IsMasterNoCredit, 
    CutOffDate, DisableConfRes, MasterSessionId, 
    Case When Days = 1 Then 'Scheduled Date/Time' Else 'Scheduled Date(s)/Time(s)' End As daysMessage, 
    Location.Name, econtent, InstructorId, PaymentInstr, 
    SpecialInstr, ContactName, ContactEmail, ContactPhone, 
    ConfCWFunctionType, ConfCWFunctionType_opt, PageNumber, 
    VideoTeleConference,  CourseType, ConferenceRequiredInd, 
    DisableConfRes, ShowSeatsRemainingOnPublic, LinkedSessionID, 
    CourseSession.CourseNum, PublicStandardKey, 
    PublicMasterKey, PublicBreakoutKey 
FROM 
    CourseSession 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    Location ON CourseSession.LocNum = Location.LocNum 
INNER JOIN
    Course On CourseSession.CourseNum = Course.CourseNum 
WHERE 
    Course.CourseNum = 1944 
    AND (Course.DisplayStartingDate IS NULL 
         OR DATEDIFF(n, Course.DisplayStartingDate, GETDATE()) >= 0) 
    AND (CourseSession.DisplayDate IS NULL 
         OR DATEDIFF(n, CourseSession.DisplayDate, GETDATE()) >= 0) 
    AND ((CourseType = 0 AND CourseSession.ShowThruDate + ' 11:59:59 PM' >= GetDate()) OR (CourseType = 1 And Course.ConfShowThruDate + ' 11:59:59 PM' >= GetDate() AND CourseSession.ShowThruDate + ' 11:59:59 PM' >= GetDate())) AND MasterSessionID Is Null  AND SessionCancelled = 0 Order By PageNumber, ConferenceSortOrder, StartDate, StartTime, LinkedSessionID, ConferenceTitle,CASE WHEN numparticipants < Maxparticipants THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, Location.Name
```

I have similar (actually same) database structure for diiferent clients who use the app.

I observed that this query gives `'Ambiguous column name'` error only for few clients while for others it works fine.

I'm unable to figure out the reason for this.

**EDIT**: I run the query on same version of SQL Server 2008.

1. Changing the order by clause fixes this;but **i need to find why the
   error is not there** on other databases even though i run the same
   query on them which have same db structure.

Comment: You're already saying, specifically, that you want `CourseSession.ConferenceTitle`, not just *any* `ConferenceTitle`. No ambiguity because you've already been specific.

Comment: you should use table aliases!!!! that's bad coding imho

Comment: the scenario im trying to explain is when im not specifying the tablename. Thats what im unable to figure out.Even without specifying the table name im not getting error on some databases while others give me the error.

Comment: Fix the code by using aliases and specifying which table every column comes from and it fixes the error. The error is present because the code is lazy.

Comment: Every field you're pulling back in your select should specify the table that you're pulling it from.  This makes it easier to maintain long term, in case you ever need to join on a new table and add more fields to the query.  As stated by a few others here, the best way to do that is with a table alias (although you could simply specify the full table name for each property).

Comment: Why do you need to find why the error is sometimes not there?  Just fix the error.

Comment: That's exactly what i thought after fixing this; but i'm answerable for this.

Comment: the order clause uses the output. as long as there are no two columns `conferencetitle` in your columnlist, you are fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Changing the order by clause fixes this;but i need to find why the
>   error is not there on other databases even though i run the same query
>   on them which have same db structure.

The behavior has changed between SQL Server 2000 and SQL Server 2005.

Read the Microsoft answer to the following connect item for more details on why it was done:

- [Behaviour Change 2000->2005: Ambiguous column name error using a column twice](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/203628/behaviour-change-2000-2005-ambiguous-column-name-error-using-a-column-twice)

> Thank you for the report. This change is by design and was done as
>   part of an overall effort to make binding of column names more
>   predictable and align it with the SQL Standard. Among the other
>   changes were: not to ignoring column prefixes and limiting column
>   references to 2-part names instead of allowing more prefixes. This was
>   done to help uncover queries that were not running as the author
>   intended or had typos or cut/paste errors. In most of the investigated
>   cases, this has proven to be beneficial. As you note, the original
>   behavior is maintained in backwards compat mode, so if you need this
>   query to continue running as-is, you'll need to use the compat mode.

What you can do to check if this is really the case is to run the following query:

```
SELECT compatibility_level
FROM sys.databases WHERE name = 'DatabaseName'
```

If the result is 80 or below, then you are running in SQL Server 2000 compatibility, so you won't experience this error.

See the 3rd item of [Differences Between Compatibility Level 80 and Level 90](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510680%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) for additional details.

Comment: I experience this error for compatibility =80 ; for 90 i have no error. Thanx for answer :)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in the `ORDER` statement where you don't specify which `ConferenceTitle` to use:

```
ORDER BY PageNumber, ConferenceSortOrder, StartDate, StartTime, LinkedSessionID, Course.ConferenceTitle
```

Comment: I've edited my answer.I know the fix for this;what im unable to understand is that why im not getting ambiguity error even when im not specifying tableName.And this happens for some databases while others it works fine.

Comment: Yes that might be a reason.Even im not sure.

Answer (score 0):

2008 incorrectly uses the alias where available to identify what to sort by. 2008R2 fixed this, in my experience.

Comment: Thanx TTG Guy ; can u please provide me some reference. Thank you

Comment: I might be mistaken. It was just my experience. This thread seems to say otherwise: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2788342/ambiguous-column-name-error-on-one-particular-server